# Como obtener clases que no sean repetidas de un Nodelist?

Tags: javascript, css3, class, selectores

Hola quisiera saber como puedo con Javascript PURO obtener nombres de clases CSS y poder mostrarlas en la consola sin repetir nombres desde una lista de nodos donde obtengo los elementos buscando la primer clase. Los elementos con la clase AAA siempre tienen 2 clases solamente: AAA y otra clase que varía y se repite:
Con esta función veo las clases pero repetidas:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.AAA'), function(elem) {
    console.log(elem.className);
});


<span class"AAA BBB"></span>
<span class"AAA CCC"></span>
<span class"AAA DDD"></span>
<span class"AAA EEE"></span>
<span class"AAA FFF"></span>
<span class"AAA GGG"></span>
<span class"AAA BBB"></span>
<span class"AAA CCC"></span>
<span class"AAA DDD"></span>
<span class"AAA EEE"></span>
<span class"AAA FFF"></span>
<span class"AAA GGG"></span>
```

Quisiera poder ver en la consola todas los tipos de clases después de obtener todos los elementos con la clase "AAA", es decir algo asi:

BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG

Tampoco me importa que se muestren ambas como AAA BBB, AAA CCC, etc.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por lo que entiendo seria algo asi (suponiendo que AAA va de primero siempre) :

```js
let arr = [...document.getElementsByClassName("AAA")].map((element) => {
  let tempArr = element.className.split(' ') // separamos las classes del array
  tempArr.shift() // quitamos el primer elemento
  return tempArr // retornamos los demas elementos
})
arr =[].concat(...arr) // unimos todos los arrays en uno solo
console.log([...new Set(arr)]) // Generamos el array con valores únicos y lo escribimos
```

```html
<span class="AAA BBB"></span>
<span class="AAA CCC"></span>
<span class="AAA DDD"></span>
<span class="AAA EEE"></span>
<span class="AAA FFF"></span>
<span class="AAA GGG"></span>
<span class="AAA BBB"></span>
<span class="AAA CCC"></span>
<span class="AAA DDD"></span>
<span class="AAA EEE"></span>
<span class="AAA FFF"></span>
<span class="AAA GGG"></span>
```